# Overriding Connection of Eloquent ->get()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to override the connection of the Eloquent ->get().

I have made my own Eloquent called `SmartEloquent` ([view old dev version on github](http://github.com/marktopper/smart-eloquent)).
It extends the original Eloquent.

I am trying to make this run another connection on usage of `->get()` like `Bear::where('id', 1)->get()`. Then it should run the connection defined as `getter`-connection.

But my problem is, how can I change the connection inside the `get`-method?

Comment: Why do you have to set the connection in `get()`? Or in other words, what's wrong with Eloquent's `on()` method?

Comment: You can't. You would need to recreate the query, since `Query\Builder` doesn't let you set the connection after instantiation. How and why do you want it? Are you aware of [read/write connections](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#read-write-connections) and very end of this [model connections](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage)?

Comment: Well, the problem is that my `SmartEloquent` package requires to be able to change it inside the `get` method.

But I fixed it, problem was I could not override the connection since it was already initialized. So I had to recreate it. Thanks to @JarekTkaczyk